# default fields not working with an Embedded field on save(), in a django project with mongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, pymongo, djongo

Let's say I have the below structure of Models for a django project with MongoDB Database, using djongo as DB engine.

When I am trying to add a Department record, if I don't provide the salary field which is marked as `default=0` in the model declaration, I get a `ValidationError` for not supplied fields

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    salary = models.FloatField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, null=False)
    persons = models.EmbeddedField(model_container=Person)
```

If I run the below query (Without providing the salary field at all):

```
Department(
    name='Networking',
    persons = {
        'name': 'Mike',
        'surname': 'Jordan'
    }
 ).save()
```

I get a Validation error for not supplied field (Since is marked as `default=0`, why django asks for it ?):

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['{\'salary\': [\'Value for field "Project.Person.salary" not supplied\']
```

Comment: I have the same issue, Have you fixed it?

Comment: my question is : you use django model for mongo?‌ u edited model ? 
ur problem with validation in fields of model , if u edit that u delete some other codes related to validation

Comment: @MiladVayani I have not understood exactly what you are asking me

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue when using MongoDB and Djongo and when trying to perform my **migrate** step.

It seems that Django kept some outdate definitions of my models in the my database (in the collections "django_..."), in which the "now nullable" field was "not nullable".

The workaround solution I found was to delete manually all "django_..." collections from my database and doing makemigrations + migrate back again. Then it worked.